# Set line number for custom compiler error

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I am working on an Eclipse plugin and would like to make some of his suggestions to be compiler errors if not handled and so I created a Compilation Participant that always creates a compilation error.
My code:

```
public class compilerNotificator extends CompilationParticipant{
    @Override
    public int aboutToBuild(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final IJavaProject project){
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isActive(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final IJavaProject project){
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void reconcile(final ReconcileContext context){
        final CategorizedProblem[] problems = new CategorizedProblem[1];
        problems[0] = new CategorizedProblem() {

            @Override
            public void setSourceStart(final int sourceStart) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void setSourceLineNumber(final int lineNumber) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void setSourceEnd(final int sourceEnd) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public boolean isWarning() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isError() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public int getSourceStart() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 3;
            }

            @Override
            public int getSourceLineNumber() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 10;
            }

            @Override
            public int getSourceEnd() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 34;
            }

            @Override
            public char[] getOriginatingFileName() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public String getMessage() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return "This is some fucked up shit";
            }

            @Override
            public int getID() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 1000129;
            }

            @Override
            public String[] getArguments() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public String getMarkerType() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return "Bad";
            }

            @Override
            public int getCategoryID() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 5;
            }
        };
        context.putProblems("test", problems);
    }
}
```

I read the CustomizedProblem Description online and getSourceLineNumber is supposed to tell the compiler the problem's line for the problem requestor (its called something like that, its part of the compiler anyway) but the function isnt even being called (I added some prints in it and it wasnt called) eclipse just says the compiler error I created is in the first line always.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Your CategorizedProblem can only have the right line number if you put it in there. *You're* the one adding it.

Comment: Maybe I didnt explain my self properly, I edited it and i did tell it the number in the getSourceLineNumber function but it doesnt seem to have any effect...

Comment: Try also having values for source start and source end. The line number alone is really only useful in the Views.

Comment: Tried also setting source start and end to the same line number and still nothing...

Comment: compilerNotificator is being called, though?

Comment: yes, some of the problem's methods are begin called just not getSourceLineNum or getSourceEnd/Start